# Weird memory address issue in Swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am unable to figure out how to get the correct memory address for a computed variable defined inside a class/struct. I defined a class in the following way (similar way for struct also):

```
class TestClass {
    private var a = "Hello"
    
    var getterSetter: String {
        get {
            return a
        }
        set {
            a = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I define my ViewController as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let testClass = TestClass()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        demoMethod()
        
        print("--------")
        print(testClass.getterSetter)    //Prints "I'm here"
        
        /// Address of testClass
        print("Address of testClass: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self.testClass).toOpaque())")
        
        /// Address of computed variable in testClass
        withUnsafePointer(to: &self.testClass.getterSetter) {
            print("Address of computed variable: \(String(format: "%p", $0.pointee))")
        }
        print("--------")
        
    }
    
    private func demoMethod() {
        Observable.just(())
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.testClass.getterSetter = "I'm here"
                
                print("*****")
                /// Address of testClass
                print("Address of testClass: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self.testClass).toOpaque())")
                
                /// Address of computed variable in testClass
                withUnsafePointer(to: &self.testClass.getterSetter) {
                    print("Address of computed variable: \(String(format: "%p", $0.pointee))")
                }
                print("*****")
            })
            .disposed(by: DisposeBag())
    }
}
```

The value of **getterSetter** variable is accessed and set inside **demoMethod** function, using a simple **Observable**, which in turn changes **a** to **"I'm here"**. I'm printing the addresses of testClass and getterSetter variable inside the demoMethod function as well as after this function returns.

Please have a look at the link here, that shows output.

[image: Output here]

As we can see from the image, *the testClass instance address remains same*, as expected. But, *the getterSetter variable's address is shown different each time it is printed*, which does not make sense because the **private variable a** gets changed to **"I'm here"** (can be seen in the output link), implying that they should point to same memory.

If I remove **self.testClass.getterSetter = "I'm here"** from **demoMethod**, it starts giving correct and same memory addresses like this:

[image: Updated Output]

- *I believe it has to do something with **Copy on Write** mechanism, but I'm unable to figure out exactly what. If the original instance is
  copied to a new memory when I do **self.testClass.getterSetter = "I'm here"**, then how come value of **a** got changed at
  original memory address?*
- So, what exactly is going on here and how is memory getting
  allocated?

**P.S.** Also, the exact same thing is observed when I use **struct TestClass** in place of **class TestClass** with only difference being, I print using **print("Address of testClass: (String(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self.testClass, to: String.self)))")**

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you take rx-swift out of the equation?

Comment: @de. Yes same issue happens even without using rx-swift.

Comment: I recommend you remove it from your example then to facilitate for people to help you.